# Zappa Deployment Error for Alexa Skill: Object 'NoneType' not callable?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, openssl, alexa-skills-kit, zappa

Whenever I try to deploy my Alexa Skill (for the Amazon Promotion) I see this error when I go to the web address of the endpoint:

```
"{'message': 'An uncaught exception happened while servicing this request. You can investigate this with the `zappa tail` command.', 'traceback': ['Traceback (most recent call last):\\n', '  File \"/var/task/handler.py\", line 433, in handler\\n    response = Response.from_app(self.wsgi_app, environ)\\n', '  File \"/var/task/werkzeug/wrappers.py\", line 903, in from_app\\n    return cls(*_run_wsgi_app(app, environ, buffered))\\n', '  File \"/var/task/werkzeug/test.py\", line 884, in run_wsgi_app\\n    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)\\n', \"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable\\n\"]}"
```

After investigating this further, I ran `zappa tail` to see what the issue is.

I scrolled up through the tail and noticed this error message:

```
[1499529414189] libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory: ImportError
```

What does this mean? How can I resolve this? I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.6 using flask-ask.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to correct this my installing everything from scratch according the instructions at https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/8e8ad73a-99e9-4c0f-a7b3-60f92287b0bf/new-alexa-tutorial-deploy-flask-ask-skills-to-aws-lambda-with-zappa. Something in the venv directory just got messed up.